# How to make a custom message from an already defined response on Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

My API is returning me this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "@B7304",
        "username": "blabla",
        "hearthBeat": 30,
        "status": "well",
        "date": "13/05/1333",
        "latitute": 30,
        "longitude": 40,
        "cardiacSteps": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "uuid": "@B7304",
        "username": "blabla",
        "hearthBeat": null,
        "status": null,
        "date": null,
        "latitute": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "cardiacSteps": null
    }
]
```

The problem is, I would like to, on the array that is represented by the second ID, return a error message, as there is no data in it. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "@B7304",
        "username": "blabla",
        "hearthBeat": 30,
        "status": "well",
        "date": "13/05/1333",
        "latitute": 30,
        "longitude": 40,
        "cardiacSteps": 50
    },
    {
        "uuid": @B7304,
        "message": "This user has no data"
    }
]
```

My code is as follows:

```
    @GetMapping("/monitored")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') and hasRole('RESPONSIBLE')")
    public Object returnMonitored() {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Optional<User> username = userRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName());

        List<Dependency> uuids = dependencyRepository.returnAllUserUuid(Objects.requireNonNull(username.orElse(null)).getUuid());
        List<Health> health = new ArrayList<>();

        uuids.forEach(uuid -> {
                    if (userRepository.existsByUuid(uuid.getUserUuid()) && healthRepository.existsByUuid(uuid.getUserUuid())) {

                        if(healthRepository.existsByUuid(uuid.getUserUuid()) && healthRepository.isRegistered(uuid.getUserUuid())) {
                            List<Health> healthList = healthRepository.returnAllUserUuid(uuid.getUserUuid());
                            health.addAll(healthList);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        if(health == null || health.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new MessageVo("You're not responsible for any user ;) "));
        }

        return health;
    }
```

With this, I can't seem to override the specific response, as it is an List of the Entity(Health).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is a **really** bad idea since one would expect all elements in a JSON array to have the same attributes.

You should return what you are returning now with all the nulls and return your "message" in status.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "@B7304",
        "username": "blabla",
        "hearthBeat": 30,
        "status": "well",
        "date": "13/05/1333",
        "latitute": 30,
        "longitude": 40,
        "cardiacSteps": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "uuid": "@B7304",
        "username": "blabla",
        "hearthBeat": null,
        "status": "This user has no data",
        "date": null,
        "latitute": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "cardiacSteps": null
    }
]
```

I would also recommend adding a "statusCode" attribute where you can return a numerical code and have "status" represent the statusCode description since doing string compares on status isn't a good idea either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, SledgeHammer. I was thinking of making each field a String. And then defaulting them to: "There is no data". What do you think?

Comment: @Raven Nah, no reason to needlessly make the response large.

Answer (score 0):

In your health class, add the @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL), values that are null will not be shown on your response. Take note to use the boxed type and not the primitive type.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Health {
    Integer id;
    String uuid;
    ... 
    String message;
}
```

Comment: @Raven Yeah, you could go this route, but personally, I'd use the "id" as the "PK", so if you make it null and hide it, that'll break that concept. It doesn't make sense to have a null id anyways imo. Not a big fan of hiding nulls.

Comment: @Raven Good practice is to return nulls to keep the json shape consistent, to keep the key/value pairs consistent, etc.

Comment: @SledgeHammer. Thanks so much for your time! I'll let them be null, then.